# How does facebook make the char bar always remains at the bottom of the browser

Tags: html, css, facebook

I just want to know how does facebook makes the chat bar always remains the bottom of the browser whether or not we scroll on the page[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

1. Use `position:fixed` to make the bar fixed
2. Use `z-index` to make the bar displays on top.
3. [Tutorial](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/facebook-style-footer-admin-panel-part-1/) how to make footer bar like Facebook. *Old version*

Answer (score 2):

You use the CSS [fixed position](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp).

Example:

```
{position:fixed; bottom:0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
position:fixed;bottom:0;right:5%
```

C/P from Facebook

```
#chat{bottom:0;direction:ltr;height:25px;position:fixed;right:0;z-index:104;}
```